# This bug only exists on the device. Everything works great in the simulator

Tags: parsing, networking, webclient

This bug only exists on the device. Everything works great in the simulator.

Our application downloads a descent number of files. After that I parse an obj
and mtl file for 3D data. Then if I try to download more files it downloads
about 10 or so files and then starts sending them to the connection queue at
which time every download times out. If I gracefully eject from the downloads
and then try again every file times out. It is like the network connection just
disappears. This only happens after I run the parse. If I remove the parse
everything works great.